# Error Passing Prop in Navigation - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native. I think this issue is probably trivial but all of the tutorials I have followed all lead to errors.

I have basic List Item that contains an onPress function that sets props to be passed to a new screen like this:

```
<ListItem
  roundAvatar
  title={`${item.name} ${item.name}`}
  subtitle={item.name}

  containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
  onPress={() => this.onPress()}
/>
```

My onPress function looks like this:

```
onPress(){
    this.props.navigator.push({name:'Details', user: 'test'});
}
```

Here are my routes:

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator( 
{
Home: {
  screen: HomeScreen,
},
Details: {
  screen: DetailsScreen,
},
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
}
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push`). How do I fix this? It's not making much sense. 
Thanks in advance. (testing on an Android device)

Comment: do not follow onPress={() => this.onPress()} style. Every time a component gets rendered it is creating a new onPress function. Instead use style followed in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also send props through navigation like this

declare

```
Class Example{

render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
return(
     <ListItem
      roundAvatar
      title={`${item.name} ${item.name}`}
      subtitle={item.name}

      containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
      onPress={ navigate('screenName',{ name: 'Details',user: 'Test',})}
    />
 )
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the way you have declared onPress method.

Regular functions have their own this scope thus when you call this.props it is searching in the scope of the function and not in the parent class.

Solution 1:Using Arrow Function (Recommended)
Declare your function as arrow function as they **do not have** their own **this scope**. Thus they will use this scope of their parent class.

```
onPress=()=>{
    this.props.navigator.push({name:'Details', user: 'test'});
}
```

Solution 2:Using bind this

```
Class ExampleComponent{
onPress(){
//this is not defined
}

render(){
return(
         <ListItem
          roundAvatar
          title={`${item.name} ${item.name}`}
          subtitle={item.name}

          containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
          onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}
        />
     )
  }
}
```